# How to handle global state in GO

Tags: go

I recently joined a project where there's an external configuration style service - basically a KV store that's called with jsonrpc.

Don't ask why it's there..

I need to query this config service to obtain a whitelist used internally within the codebase.

However, I can't come to a solution without using a global var. For example I call a function to get the config from package `A` but must export the var for it to be used within other packages. My original solution was to use `gocache` setting the cache within a package and exporting the cache accessor to have some type restriction. However, this added complexity and seemed too much rather than just storing the val in an exported var.

I have seen global vars used within the standard library but am confused as this would go against the law of encapsulation?

Would appreciate any advice how to approach a problem like this.

Comment: Whoever told you that global variables are bad per se or that nothing ever must be exported was wrong. Some things simply _are_ global so stuff them into a variable or have a exported function. There is no problem here.

Comment: Can you create a settings package, which can be used in other packages as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is small or is not expected to change much, then a global
config could be okay. I’d put the config variable in a package of its own though. On the other hand, if the project is expected grow over
time, it makes sense to have things encapsulated.

Can you pass the config as a parameter from package `A` to any other package
that needs it in the form of method or constructor args? I think passing things
around makes the dependency on the config obvious and also allows for easier
mocking in tests.

Personally I'd structure the project like this (if i was working from scratch -
probably not a luxury you have):

```
project root
|
|- config/
|  |- Config (interface) -> knows how to fetch config form JSON-RPC and caches it if necessary
|  |  |- GetSomething1()
|  |  |- GetSomething2()
|  |  |- Get(key string) -> If you have arbitrary keys
|  |
|  |- NewJsonRpcConfig(settings) -> returns something that implements the Config interface
|
|- main.go -> calls config.NewConfig()
   |
   |- Passes the resulting Config interface as a parameter to anything that needs it.
      Packages don't directly interact with a global variable.
```

All the config stuff is in the `config` package. It can talk to the JSON-RPC
server, maybe cache the results and return the config. The `main` package
creates an instance of the config fetcher and passes it to all instances that
need to use the config.